# MS Word Document Operations are not working with IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I have opened a word document as follows

```
*Application wordApp = new ApplicationClass();
Document doc = null;
doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref docPath,
  ref setFalse, ref setFalse, ref setFalse, ref missing,
  ref missing, ref setTrue, ref missing, ref missing,
  ref missing, ref missing, ref setFalse, ref setFalse,
  ref missing, ref setTrue, ref missing);*
```

This is working fine with development server. But in IIS this is not working
I have already given permission to ASPNET user in IIS,Folder and in dcomcnfg.
Please help to solve this.

Comment: what do you mean is not working?

Comment: Microsoft **does not support** Office automation from any non-interactive application (including ASP.NET) because it may exhibit unstable behavior or deadlocks. See support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 for details.

Comment: not working means it hangs on that line of code for opening the document..

Answer (score 2):

Typically the accounts running web processes don't have enough os permissions to run GUI apps like Word. This is probably a good thing in most cases as one really shouldn't run GUI apps from web processes. What happens when word springs a modal dialog that blocks the entire site and no one is available to visit the web server and click OK. If you must read word docs, a library is a much better solution.

All that said, using word here makes zero sense -- you are just loading some stop words from a file. Plain text would be just as effective and vastly easier to deal with.

Comment: Please suggest any library we can use.